# Click event return undefined. Why?

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular8

I'm trying to pass a date taken from one of the mat-option choices but when in the mat-option tag I put a click method with event and print the event it returns `undefined`!
How can i do to solve?

HTML

```
    <mat-drawer-content class="Font">
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>choose the date
        </mat-label>
        <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
          <mat-option value="option1" (click)="onclick($event)">{{this.shareDate.newCurrentDate}}</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="option2" (click)="onclick($event)">{{this.shareDate.newTomorrow}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field >
        <mat-label>choose the time
        </mat-label>
        <mat-select #hasBackdrop>
          <mat-option [value]="false" *ngFor="let time of dayaHours">
            <div class="hourTime">{{formatTime(time.time)}}</div>
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-drawer-content>
  </mat-drawer-container>
```

TS

```
onclick(event) {
  console.log(event.value); // undefined
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to see what event is? `console.log(event);`

Comment: yes, give me a mouse event

Comment: Does it have `value` inside? You should add it in your question.

Comment: event.value is undefinited, event give me a mouse event

Comment: `event.target.value` ?

Comment: event.target.value on console.log is undefinited  :(

Comment: Is there any reason, why you listen to the click event of the options instead of the selectionChange event from mat-select? https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelect the selectionChange output carries a MatSelectChange model, which does contain the value https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelectChange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible because click event does not carry any value.
Alternative I suggest you to do the follow:

```
<mat-option #matOption1 (click)="onClick(matOption1.value)" [value]="'GB'">Great Britain</mat-option>
```

I have created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-dmkrtz?file=src/app/app.component.html) also.

For more information you can read: https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables